# Active Directory: Domain Group Policy: How to modify for specific server?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Our domain policy is restricting access to a server.... Specifically, I need to grant the "allow log on locally" right to some local users on a server.

However, gpedit, on that server, will not let me do this, because the policy is controlled by the domain policy.

How do I loosen this up, just for this one server (that is part of the domain), so that I can get things working?

I tried, in the Group Policy Management Editor (the only tool that seems to let me edit the policy), adding: `localserver\username` but the tool said "accounts could not be validated..."

Thanks!

Comment: Edit the Domain based policy to meet your needs. You can't over ride it with the local policy.

Comment: @joeqwerty But how do I add localuser\jose to the domain policy? (I tried, and the tool said it could not validate the user)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: in gpmc, when you add the user, you must press Locations and set the scope of the user name search to the actual server, or as close to it as possible.... and then it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the specific GPO to restrict to use gpedit.msc? If yes, you can create a new OU on the AD without the GPO (or without any GPO assigned). Move the server to the new OU --> Logoff/Login back to the server. Now you're working your server with different policies. Run RSOP.msc to verify the specific GPO's.